# chemfig radical inside of aromatic structure

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to get a delocalized radical inside an aromatic structure.

Example:

```
\chemfig{**6(------)}
```

should be made to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an invisible bond:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{**6(--(-[::120,,,,draw=none].)----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]